# Компилятор не пускает одно из (по сути одинаковых) выражений

Tags: java

```
    int i=0;
    double d = 0d;
    i +=d;      //the compiler says it's OK
    i = i + d;  // ...this is wrong!!!  эту строчку компилятор не пускает
```

Объясните мне в чём проблема?
Java 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведение типов встроено в оператор +=.
Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

То есть,

```
i += d
```

превращается в

```
i = (int)(i + d)
```